# mapbox GL js: road rendering wrong at tile edge

Tags: rendering, mapbox, vector-tiles

Recently,our project use mapnik to generate Mapbox Vector Tile,and use mapbox GL js to render the mvt file.
But there is an rendering issue: the road line rending wrong at tile edge.the Endpoints at the tile edge do not align.there are some loopholes.
Not all tile edge have this issue, just some one has this issue, especially for the road which have a big angle of inclination with tile edge.
Is there some advance to fix this issue ? thanks.

Please note the below picture:

[image]

Yue

Comment: Any expert help to give some suggestion ？

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Did you try opening an issue on their github repository?